# Shortcut keys nuisance in my computer

Tags: remote-desktop, operating-system

after login to my windows 2003 server terminal and start typing some thing in the notepad for some letter like E and so on..i am getting some fuctionalities

if i type letter E  explorer will pop up

how to get rid of this?

Comment: WIndows Key + E is the shortcut to open Explorer...sounds like its stuck. When you press 'R' does the Run box appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the state of the "Windows Key" is getting "stuck" in Remote Desktop sessions.

The discussion in this posting has some ideas http://michaelshadle.com/2007/09/19/windows-key-stuck-in-remote-desktop/

Zow... it looks like this is a long-standing bug.

Looks like you can disable the "Windows Key" in the registry on the terminal server as a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Some workarounds for this bug in Remote Desktop:

1. Close Remote Desktop Connection
2. Open a new Remote Desktop Connection, setting "Apply Windows Key Combinations" to "On the remote computer"
3. Press the `Ctrl Alt End` and lock the computer
4. Login again and it should work.

or simpler:

Open the virtual keyboard, press the Windows key several times to release it.

Comment: +1 This is what I've done in the past and has worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your Windows key is stuck.  First attempted resolution method is percussive maintenance: whack it a few times.

Comment: "Percussive maintenance"... heh heh... I like that. I'll have to remember to use that.

Answer (score 1):

Just now, I experienced this problem and it was driving me nuts. The simplest that you can do is - press the Windows key from your physical keyboard several times to get rid of this crazy bug. I am glad it worked for me.